# How can I access IPhone camera to take a picture Using corona

Tags: lua, camera, coronasdk

I'm new to programming and making an app for iphone and android with Corona SDK.I want to take a picture with Iphone camera and then save it for further work . How can I access the camera of a device in corona . Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use media.show() to use the camera in Corona.

Here is the API reference page:
http://developer.anscamobile.com/reference/index/mediashow

And a usage example:

```
local onComplete = function(event)
local photo = event.target
    print( "photo w,h = " .. photo.width .. "," .. photo.height )
end

media.show( media.Camera, onComplete )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code it may useful to you,

```
local listener = function( event )
    if media.hasSource( media.Camera ) then
        media.show( media.Camera, sessionComplete )
    else
        native.showAlert("Corona", "Camera not found.")
    end
    return true
end

frameRect:addEventListener("tap",listener);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below url for implementing Camera successfully in your Corona App -
**http://developer.coronalabs.com/content/camera**

Answer (score -1):

I've had a look at [the API](http://developer.anscamobile.com/resources/apis/) and it seems that you can't access the camera from Corona.

Comment: I had searched a lot too , didn't find anything related but there  must be some way to do that in corona ...! its a basic function and I don't think corona didn't gave this support.

Comment: I think I found some useful info here regarding camera in Corona SDK. http://developer.anscamobile.com/content/camera